# Is there a way to override meteor js helper from outside

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a template grid_list

```
<template name="grid_list">
        {{#each items}}
            bla
        {{/each}}
</template>
```

grid_list helpers:

```
Template.grid_list.helpers({
  items: function() {
    return [1, 2, 3];
  }
});
```

I call grid_list from other template

{{> grid_list}}

Can I somehow pass other variable to grid_list that overrides items helper result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>The data context has precedence over helpers, so you can use this to achieve what you want.</s>

```html
<template name="test">
    {{> grid_list myDataContext}}
</template>

<template name="grid_list">
    {{#each items}}
        bla
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.test.helpers({
    myDataContext: function () {
        return {
            items: [2, 5, 4, 6]
        }
    }
})
```

In the `items` helper, you can check if the data context contains the array, and return appropriate value. For example:

```html
<template name="test">
    {{> grid_list myDataContext}}
</template>

<template name="grid_list">
    {{#each items}}
        <p>{{this}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.test.helpers({
    myDataContext: function () {
        return {
            items: [2, 5, 4, 6]
        }
    }
})

Template.grid_list.helpers({
    items: function() {

        data = Template.instance().data

        if(data.hasOwnProperty('items')){
            return data.items
        }else{
            return [1, 2, 3]
        }

    }
})
```

Comment: As far as I can see it doesn't work: http://meteorpad.com/pad/xDmJEASai5sALAzry/Leaderboard

Comment: @ivan133 Oh, this is embarrassing. I actually wasn't sure if data context had precedence over helpers or not, so I created a test project, and it confirmed it, but I guess I must have done something wrong in my test project. Sorry! ^^' I've updated my answer with a new solution, although it's not as nice as the first on would be :/